# What comes first: Permission or validity check?

Tags: validation, rest, permissions

I am building a REST API and I cannot decide what to check first: Input validity or permissions. Imagine a user tries to post invalid date to an endpoint they are not allowed to access. Should the response be a `403 Unauthorized` or a `400 Bad Request`?

Furthermore: Is there some "official" spec which describes this and what are the reasons why one would lean to one or the other?

Comment: I personally think if you have a preference to do large amounts of transactions through the API, go for validation then authorization. This saves time (My personnel opinion ). If you are looking for some sort of standards, W3C is always a good place to start: http://www.w3.org/TR/ws-arch/